# При скроле менять класс у body

Tags: javascript, jquery

Никак не получается решить задачку:

Использую scrollify.js на сайте (при скроле вниз/вверх переходим к следующему блоку). В body мне надо добавлять класс с индексом текущего слайда:

```
<body class="desktop-page slider-1">  // открыт первый слайдер
<body class="desktop-page slider-2"> // открыт второй слайдер и т.д...
```

Я пробовал сделать так:

```
var sno = index+1; // Получаем текущий индекс слайда
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className = 'desktop-page slider-'+sno; // Перезаписываем класс
```

Да, так все работает, но проблема в том, что мне надо не трогать класс desktop-page, то есть менять только **slider-(тут индекс текущего слайда)**.

Была еще попытка сделать так:

```
$("body").removeClass("slider-" + String(sno-1));
$("body").addClass("slider-" + String(sno));
```

Так все работает только при скроле вниз. Когда скролим наверх получается хаос.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такое? Можно на JS, можно на jquery. Без разницы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну только клик замени на скролл по условиям.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const btnr = document.getElementById('btnr');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add('class1');
});

btnr.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove('class1');
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="btn">add class</p>
<p id="btnr">remove class</p>
```

Comment: У меня проблема с подхватыванием индекса слайда текущего. Прочтите еще раз вопрос.

Comment: Цитата из вопроса `но проблема в том, что мне надо не трогать класс desktop-page, то есть менять только slider-(тут индекс текущего слайда)`. Я понял, что вопрос в том, как дать объекту класс, не трогая уже примененный. [Этим](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) методом можем отследить позицию нужного объекта. Если он на экране, дать класс такой-то, убрать класс такой-то.